# UIImageView - UIScrollView Fill and set X to 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

StackOverflow.. last resort as I hate bothering other devs but I've come to the end of my tether with my problem..

I have a UIView, in which are 2 UIScrollViews - in each scrollview is a UIImageView. The original idea is that I can move the image in each scroll view on the Y Axis to reposition the images.

Currently, the UIImageViews are using the content mode of (so the images don't stretch and display in full):

```
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

The images load fine into the ScrollViews - the only problem is, the position of the UIImageView's are centred on the Y Axis and I need them to be 0! I've tried setting the UIImageView frame after adding and setting the content mode but nothing.

Here is my code:

```
- (outletContainer is a UIView)
- (imagePack is an NSMutableArray of UIImages)

UIImageView *tempFirst = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imagePack objectAtIndex:0]];
[tempFirst setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, outletContainer.frame.size.width, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2)];
[tempFirst setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

// add scrollview for positioning:
UIScrollView *firstScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[firstScroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tempFirst.image.size.width, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2)];
[firstScroller setContentSize:tempFirst.image.size];
[firstScroller addSubview:tempFirst];
[outletContainer addSubview:firstScroller];

UIImageView *tempSecond = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imagePack objectAtIndex:1]];
[tempSecond setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, outletContainer.frame.size.width, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2)];
[tempSecond setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

// add scrollview for positioning:
UIScrollView *secondScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[secondScroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2, tempSecond.image.size.width, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2)];
[secondScroller setContentSize:tempSecond.image.size];
[secondScroller addSubview:tempSecond];
[outletContainer addSubview:secondScroller];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to delete these two lines:

```
[tempFirst setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, outletContainer.frame.size.width, tempFirst.image.size.height*tempF)];

[tempSecond setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, outletContainer.frame.size.width, outletContainer.frame.size.height/2)];
```

When you create an UIImageView with image it takes UIImage size.

Edited:

Ok, then you have to do that:

```
[tempFirst setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, outletContainer.frame.size.width, tempFirst.image.size.height*outletContainer.frame.size.width/tempFirst.image.size.width)];
 firstScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(outletContainer.frame.size.width, tempFirst.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Almost worked! The size of the UIImage is a bit too high though - need the width and height to scale down to the width of the scrollview - thanks for the help! (: